# CSS: How to fit a circular progress bar according to screen size (mobile)

Tags: css, coffeescript, progress-bar, pug

this is more of a CSS question.

I have gotten the code to create a circular progress bar from this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Aapn8/3410/). I have pasted the code below as well.

Currently, when I used the code, it creates a circular progress bar that is fixed in position and size. i.e. does not expand or shrink with screen size.

[image]

**Question**:
How can I update the CSS such that it allows the size of the circular bar and to fit the size of the screen? Because, the circular bar should fit nicely for different mobile screen sizes.

[image]

## Code to create a circular progress bar (Coffescript)

```
el = document.getElementById('graph')
# get canvas
options = 
  percent: el.getAttribute('data-percent')
  size: el.getAttribute('data-size') or 220
  lineWidth: el.getAttribute('data-line') or 20
  rotate: el.getAttribute('data-rotate') or 0
canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
span = document.createElement('span')
span.textContent = options.percent + '%'
if typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined'
 G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement canvas
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = canvas.height = options.size
el.appendChild span
el.appendChild canvas
ctx.translate options.size / 2, options.size / 2
# change center
ctx.rotate (-1 / 2 + options.rotate / 180) * Math.PI
# rotate -90 deg
#imd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 240, 240);
radius = (options.size - (options.lineWidth)) / 2

drawCircle = (color, lineWidth, percent) ->
  percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, percent or 1), 1)
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.arc 0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2 * percent, false
  ctx.strokeStyle = color
  ctx.lineCap = 'round'
  # butt, round or square
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
  ctx.stroke()
  return

drawCircle '#efefef', options.lineWidth, 100 / 100
drawCircle '#555555', options.lineWidth, options.percent / 100
```

## CSS

```
.progress_chart {
  position:relative;
  margin: 80px;
  width: 220px; height: 220px;
  canvas {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
  }
  span {
    color:#555;
    display:block;
    line-height:220px;
    text-align:center;
    width:220px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight:100;
    margin-left:5px;
  }

  input {
    width: 200px;
  }  
}
```

## JADE Code

```
.progress_chart
  #graph.chart(data-percent='14')
```

---

## Update

Screenshot of pixelated graph
[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding "max-width: 80vw" to the .progress_chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following uses the css3 View-port units `vw, vh, vmin, vmax` to address this. Basically the html elements' (`canvas, span, div`) height will be assigned according to the view-port's Width & Height. [See detail explanation](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/)

By using `vmin` (size of the smallest-side of the view-port) we can adjust the appropriate height/width to match the screen-size.

```
  div {
  /* take the viewport Width & Height */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  /* horizontal centers content */
  text-align: center;
  /* vertical centers content */
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

canvas {
  width: auto;
  /* 90% of smallest-side */
  height: 90vmin;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  /* 20% of smallest-side */
  font-size: 20vmin;
  /* 90% of smallest-side */
  line-height: 90vmin;
  /* 90% of smallest-side */
  width: 90vmin;
}
```

[See demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPJyRP)

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. On a separate note, the progress chart looks very pixelated. Is there anyway to fix that? (attached screenshot in OP)

Comment: That because css is being used to manipulate the W and H of a canvas, which stretches pixels inside the canvas. To avoid this you need to use canvas `height` and `width` attributes of the canvas directly. In your case following js change will increase the canvas width to match current view-port size. [See edits in Js] (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPJyRP?editors=0010)

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
var options = {
    ....
    size: el.getAttribute('data-size') || (screen.width - 5),
    lineWidth: el.getAttribute('data-line') || 50,
    ....
}::::::::::::::::::

Comment: This is great! Works. Thanks alot for your help on this.